# Exercises on stochastic calculus

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes

Where I can find exercises on stochastic calculus (stochastic integration, SDE)? I'm mostly interested in medium difficulty exercises, preferably not proof-oriented, ideally with solutions. I've already looked through the books of Øksendal, Protter, Kuo. Thank you.

Comment: I think [this book](http://ebooks.cambridge.org/ebook.jsf?bid=CBO9780511610813) by Loic Chaumont and M. Yor nicely fits your requirements. On the bottom of the webpage there is free pdf with table of contents.

Comment: Small hint: solutions to the exercises from the first three chapters of Protters book are available on his homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book [Theory of Stochastic Processes: With Applications to Financial Mathematics](http://books.google.com/books?id=8Nzn51YTbX4C&pg=PR8&dq=kukush+Theory+of+Stochastic+Processes&hl=en&ei=A87STqaPOsr4sgb9j5X-DA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=kukush%20Theory%20of%20Stochastic%20Processes&f=false) is probably what you are looking for. Hints and solutions to some problems along with review of needed theory are included.

Also the book of Revuz, Yor [Continuous martingales and Brownian motion](http://books.google.com/books?id=1ml95FLM5koC&printsec=frontcover&dq=revuz+yor+continuous+martingales&hl=en&ei=uM7STtKSJNDGtAbKy9DvDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=revuz%20yor%20continuous%20martingales&f=false) contains of lot of exercises. Solutions are not included..

Comment: Exercises from the Revuz and Yor's book are paticularly hard IMO (though very interesting), I wouldn't recommand it for someone looking for medium level exercises. Best regards.